# Satis - Mirror Repositories Package-Type

Tags: php, package, composer-php, components, satis

I am building a private satis repository (mirrored proxy).

Anyone got an idea how to make satis create a tar from packages defined under repositories like this:

```
{
  "name": "Satis Configuration",
  "homepage": "https://satis.example.org",
  "repositories": [
    { "type": "composer", "url": "https://packagist.org" },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "components/placeholdersjs",
        "type": "component",
        "version": "4.0.1",
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js/archive/v4.0.1.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        },
        "extra": {
          "component": {
            "scripts": [
              "dist/placeholders.min.js",
              "dist/placeholders.jquery.min.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "*"
  },
  "require-dependencies": true,
  "archive": {
    "directory": "dist",
    "format": "tar",
    "skip-dev": true
  }
}
```